# Tips overriding tree layout to create classic OrgChart layout in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I’m creating a dynamic (interactive click to expand/collapse) organisational chart that is based on the tree layout, however I have explicitly defined my own node placement and link routines to allow for top down and elbow path links.
I now need to add a feature to support a mixed mode layout to place some nodes vertically under their parent as opposed to displaying them on a lower Y offset and on the same X plane (horizontally).

I have just created a prototype to work with the bottom most depth and feel that this is well understood and functions. Fetching the max depth and comparing to current has done this and the tricky bit as been to calculate the dynamic spacing function.

Can anyone explain how this offsetting works with the separation function?  I’ve found that I need to set bottom most nodes to 0 as any other value will cause the widths to exponentially grow as more nodes are added as children, i.e. the parent is pushed further apart.  To counter this I have also set static spacing values to the parents.

Another thing that I have not started looking at yet is when combining the mixed layouts how to manage heights.  So I am wondering… should I bother with the spacing/separation function or just hand craft the placement in my update and enter data events.

This is where I have taken it, happy with the initial outcome.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w298I.png)

Would be good if someone could share some ideas or experiences with rolling out a custom layout.

Many thanks!
If anyone is interested, the following code is used to achieve the mixed layout.

SEPARATION FUNCTION

```
    .separation(function (a, b) {

        var separation = a.parent == b.parent ? 1.2 : 2;
        //return separation;

        //-- SKIPPING THIS CODE 
        var nodeDepth = a.depth,
            maxDepth = getMaxDepth(ancestorRoot) - 1;

        if (maxDepth !== 0) {
            var aX = Number(a.x || 0).toFixed(2),
            aY = Number(a.y || 0).toFixed(2),
            bX = Number(b.x || 0).toFixed(2),
            bY = Number(b.y || 0).toFixed(2);

            if (nodeDepth === maxDepth) {
                if ((a.parent.ID !== b.parent.ID) && (a.parent.depth === b.parent.depth)) {
                    //--Parents are at the same depth so we can adjust accordingly.
                    var parentIndex = "";
                    console.error("\tDifferent parents, but both parents are at the same depth so the separation should be marginly adjusted.");
                    separation = .1;
                }
                else if ((a.parent.ID === b.parent.ID)) {
                    console.error("\tSame parents, no separation needed.");
                    console.warn("#Separation - " + separation + " For:\n\t" + a.Props.DisplayName + " [" + aX + "," + aY + "]" + " and " + b.Props.DisplayName + " [" + bX + "," + bY + "]");
                    separation = 0;
                }
            }
            else if (nodeDepth === (maxDepth - 1)) {
                separation = 1.5;
                console.warn("#Separation - " + separation + " For:\n\t" + a.Props.DisplayName + " [" + aX + "," + aY + "]" + " and " + b.Props.DisplayName + " [" + bX + "," + bY + "]");
            }
        }
        return separation;
        //return 100;
    });
```

NODE PLACEMENT

```
function nodeTransformEnd(d, depth, i) {
    //console.info("End node transform for " + d.Props.DisplayName);
    var x0 = d.px = d.x = (((width / 2) + d.x) - boxWidth / 2);
    var y0 = d.py = d.y = (((height / 2) + d.y) - boxHeight / 2);

    var nodeDepth = d.depth,
        maxDepth = getMaxDepth(ancestorRoot) - 1;

    if (maxDepth === 0) maxDepth = -1;

    if (nodeDepth === maxDepth) {
        var index = d.parent.children.indexOf(d);
        console.log(d.Props.DisplayName +  " -> " + d.parent.Props.DisplayName + " (Depth=" + d.parent.depth + ")");
        console.log("\t Current depth: " + d.depth + ", Max depth: " + maxDepth +  ", Sibling index: " + index);
        //console.log("\t " + d.Props.DisplayName + " is index of " + index);
        //return "translate(" + x0 + "," + y0 + ")";
        x0 = d.px = d.x = (d.parent.x - ((boxWidth / 2) + 50));
        y0 = d.py = d.y = (y0 + (index * (50 + 80)));
    }


    return "translate(" + x0 + "," + y0 + ")";

} // end: util- nodeTransformEnd
```

LINK PATH

```
function drawElbowLineEnd(d, depth, i) {
    var nodeLinks = calculateNodeLinkPoints(d, depth, i),
        s = nodeLinks.source,
        t = nodeLinks.target;

    var path = [];

    var nodeDepth = d.target.depth,
        maxDepth = getMaxDepth(ancestorRoot) - 1;

    if (maxDepth === 0) maxDepth = -1;

    if (nodeDepth === maxDepth) {
        //-- Start at middle of parent node
        path.push("M", s.x, ",", s.y);
        //-- Vertical to middle of target node
        path.push("V", (t.y + (boxHeight / 2)));
        //-- Meet to the side of the child node
        path.push("H", (t.x - boxWidth / 2));

        //console.log(path.join(" "));
    }
    else {
        //-- Normal horizontal layout - elbow
        path.push("M", s.x, ",", s.y,
           "V", ((s.y + t.y) / 2),
           "H", t.x,
           "V", t.y);
    }

    return path.join("");
} // end: util- drawElbowLineEnd
```

GET MAX DEPTH

```
    var getMaxDepth = function getMaxDepth(startNode){
        startNode = startNode || ancestorRoot;
        var depth=0;
        if(startNode.children){
            startNode.children.forEach(function(child){
                var maxDepthForCurrentTree = getMaxDepth(child);
                if(maxDepthForCurrentTree > depth){
                    depth = maxDepthForCurrentTree;
                }
            });
        }
        return depth+1; 
    };
```

Comment: Think dagre-d3 will be close to what you want http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/graph-story-board.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Unless I have not paid enough attention (WBS?), this is not what I need.  I want the siblings to have their child nodes stacked vertically below. Did you see my picture? My diagram now does the whole stacking with 90 degree lines.  I was thinking that I could override the placement for depth-1 only to at least have that view and keep it with the classic horizontal layout for nodes above. Unfortunately I've not had a chance to write some code today.

Comment: Yeah i had read that I was just throwing an option just in case you have not seen d3 dagre :)

Comment: @Cyril Ah cool, thanks mate. Appreciate your time. I think I should have a solution by tomorrow, I have some ideas and I'll post something then if I can solve it before someone else does. This community has been great, really helped me with my work with d3js.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution? Would be great If you could shared it

Comment: @RobBoerman I'll have to dig out my code. I managed to get mixed layouts working, but it only worked well with the bottom most nodes rendered in a vertical layout. Client was happy so didnt try and do more. I'll try and find the solution files over the weekend.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, any advise is most welcome!